# Філіжанка чи чашка кави

Tags: синоніми, словосполучення

З чим пов'язано те, що в мові закріпився вислів **філіжанка кави**? Значно рідше зустрічається **філіжанка чаю**, натомість **чашка чаю** звучить природніше. Навіть Академічний тлумачний словник в 11 томах подає:

> Чашка, також філіжанка — невелика посудина (частіше з вушком), переважно з порцеляни, фаянсу, з якої п'ють чай, каву та інші напої.

У [статті Олександра Пономарева](http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/ukrainian/ponomariv/2011/04/post-45.html) на ВВС трапився вираз:

> Слово філіжанка вживають лише щодо посуду з якого п'ють каву (рідше чай)*.

Comment: Гадаю, що то через культурні барви, цебто відти і _кавʼярнї_, а не _чаьние лавкі_.

Comment: Звик вважати, що філіжанкою у Західних регіонах називають чашку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У Словнику української мови в 11томах на слово "[філіжанка](http://sum.in.ua/s/filizhanka)" присутній такі приклади вживання:

> *Ласточкін наточив собі окропу із самовара, плеснув густо заварки з
>   величезного чайника.., вкинув у філіжанку зернятко сахарину* (Юрій
>   Смолич, V, 1959, 461);
>
> *Купріян.. дивиться на.. філіжанку чаю, що парує на столі* (Григорій
>   Тютюнник, Вир, 1964, 415).

Тобто вживання ***філіжанка чаю*** є нормативним, хоч і не зовсім звичним.

Натомість більшого поширення набув вислів ***філіжанка кави***. На мою думку, це  можна пов'язати з походженням слова ***філіжанка***.

Згідно з ***"Етимологічним словником української мови"*** слово **"філіжанка"** має турецьке походження. В Туреччині даний посуд використовують саме для заварювання кави.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Філіжанка - чисто львівське слово (ну, вже не чисте, бо поширилося зі Львова в загальну літературну, як та ж "шкарпетка"), позначає аліґантську маленьку чашечку, з якої п'ють каву. Раджу послухати пісню Братів Гадюкіних "Роксоляна", аби відчути контекст.

> Звик вважати, що філіжанкою у Західних регіонах називають чашку.

Чашку на Галичині називають "чашка" (дивина яка!) або "горня". Що діється в інших т.зв. "Західних регіонах", не знаю.